# Equicontinuity of set of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, equicontinuity

Let $S = \{ p\in C([0,1]), p\ \text{polynomial of degree} \leq d: \max |p(x)| \leq 1 \}$

I want to show that $S$ is equicontinuous. Using the definition of equicontinuity we need for all $\epsilon >0$ exists $\delta>0$ for all $x,y \in [0,1],$ for all $p\in S $: for $d(x,y)<\delta$ we have $ |p(x) - p(y)| < \epsilon$

However I cannot bound the difference: 
$|\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_ix^i - \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_iy^i|=|\sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i(x^i-y^i)|$. We have that $|x-y|<\delta$ so $|x^i-y^i|$ is also bounded, but I think I also need a bound for $\max_{i} |c_i|$ which I cannot find.  I think that since $p(x)$ is bounded, $\max_{x\in[0,1]} p(x)$ we should be able to get an upper bound for $\max_i |c_i|$.

I would like to prove this using only the definition of equicontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S$ is equicontinuous. Let $q(x)=p((x+1)/2)$ and consider the  [Markov brothers' inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_brothers%27_inequality) for $k=1$:
$$\sup_{x\in [0, 1]}|p'(x)|=2\sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|q'(x)| \le 2d^2 \sup_{x\in [-1, 1]}|q(x)| \leq 2d^2.$$

P.S. The set $S$ is also closed:
if a sequence $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^da_k(n)x^k$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $[0,1]$ then $\max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq 1$ and $(a_k(n))_n$ is a convergent sequence for $k=0,\dots, d$ (use the fact that $(p_n(k/d))_n$ is convergent for $k=0,\dots,d$ and the Vandermonde determinant).

Comment: I haven't heard of this inequality, I thought something more elementary would be sufficient. Is it also possible to prove that $S$ is closed using this inequality?

Comment: @elrond Yes, $S$ is closed, see my P.S.